# nginx - weird ssl issue

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl

I'm experiencing a weird Nginx SSL issue that I can't seem to figure out.

What's happening is some users were receiving invalid SSL certificate errors while browsing "site2.com", in the error it was saying that the SSL for site2 was actually for site1.com so for some reason Nginx was loading the SSL from site1 for site2.

So to troubleshoot, I tried removing the entire "SITE_1" block from nginx config, and then site2.com wouldn't load at all. So I'm super confused as to what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone assist me?

```
# SITE_1
server {
    listen          443;
    ssl                     on;
    server_name  site1.com;

    client_max_body_size 10M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    ssl_certificate /home/sites/conf/ssl_site1.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/sites/conf/ssl_site1.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  25m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 240;
        proxy_connect_timeout 240;
        proxy_send_timeout 240;
        send_timeout 240;
        proxy_pass http://apache_server;
    }
}



# SITE_2
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  site2.com;

    client_max_body_size 10M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    ssl_certificate /home/sites/conf/ssl_site2.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/sites/conf/ssl_site2.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  25m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_static       on;
    gzip_buffers      16 8k;
    gzip_comp_level   9;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_min_length   0;
    gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/x-javascript;
    gzip_vary         on;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 240;
        proxy_connect_timeout 240;
        proxy_send_timeout 240;
        send_timeout 240;
        proxy_pass http://apache_server;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like site2 server declaration is missing the `ssl on;` config. In site1, you have it directly under `listen`.

Comment: That was exactly the issue, sometimes the answer is so simple! (:embarrassed:)